# Compare and change DateTime object in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, django, datetime, datetime-format

I have model in my django project, which consists field like like given below

`uploadedTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)`

And this saves dateTime object something like this.. `2022-03-21 17:53:15.156665`

I want to make such a function which will take this dateTime object from database and will compare this with **current dateTime()** object, And if there's more than 2 hours gap between them then it will return true else false.

Inshort I want all the entries from database which were inserted to database two hours ago.

I tried many ways and reading docs but can't find a correct way, Can anyone guide me how to do this?

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this snippet to find the difference between the DateTime field and the current date-time.

```
import datetime
timediff = datetime.datetime.now() - uploadedTime
hours_diff = (timediff.total_seconds()/60)/60)
if hours_diff > 2:
   return True
return False
```